# paper autocomplete suggestion source from iron-ajax response

Tags: polymer

I have create autocomplete input using `paper-autocomplete-suggestions` and I want to get a source from `iron-ajax` response, here is my code :

```
<iron-ajax id="procedureSource"
                   url="api.json">
</iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-repeat" id="sub-intents" items="{{data.data}}">
     <div class="autocomplete-wrapper">
          <paper-input name="sub_intent[procedure_id]" id="selectProcedure[[item.id]]" label="Select Procedure" on-keypress="_checkProcedureKeyPress"></paper-input>
          <paper-autocomplete-suggestions id="selectProcedureSuggestion[[item.id]]" for="selectProcedure[[item.id]]" remote-source></paper-autocomplete-suggestions>
      </div>
</template>
```

I'm using `on-keypress` event on `paper-input` to trigger `iron-ajax` request with input value length should be equal or greater than 3. here is my script :

```
<script>
Polymer({
     is: 'input-autocomplete',
     _checkProcedureKeyPress: function (event){
     var keyword = event.target.value;
     var target_id = event.target.closest('paper-input').id.replace('selectProcedure', '');
           if(keyword.length >= 3){
               this.$.procedureSource.params = {name: keyword};
               var request = this.$.procedureSource.generateRequest();
               var p = request.completes;

               p.then(function(xhr, response) {
                   var data = request.response;
                   var autocompleteSuggestions = document.querySelector('#selectProcedureSuggestion' + target_id);

                   autocompleteSuggestions.source = data;
                   autocompleteSuggestions.addEventListener('autocomplete-selected', function (event) {
                       var selected = event.detail.text;
                       console.log(selected);
                   });
               })
           }
})
</script>
```

autocomplete not showing, I'm sure the source is available from `iron-ajax` response, element target (`paper-autocomplete-suggestion` element) too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this component only processes `source` when [`remoteSource` is false](https://github.com/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/blob/5c920f1/paper-autocomplete-suggestions.html#L504), and the `source` must be set before the associated `<input>` gets a value (e.g., via static data). Otherwise with `remoteSource`, you must manually set the suggestions data (after processing raw data from the remote source).

In your case, while setting `_suggestions` (a protected property) directly would mostly work, it's probably recommended to use the element's public API for this ([`suggestions()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/elements/paper-autocomplete#method-suggestions)) so that the internal [indices are properly reset](https://github.com/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/blob/5c920f1/paper-autocomplete-suggestions.html#L526-L527).

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QaYQGN?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

I found it..
The data must be assign to [_suggestions](https://github.com/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/blob/master/paper-autocomplete-suggestions.html#L338) attribute instead of `source` attribute

```
var data = request.response;
var autocompleteSuggestions = document.querySelector('#selectProcedureSuggestion' + target_id);
autocompleteSuggestions._suggestions = data;
autocompleteSuggestions.addEventListener('autocomplete-selected', function (event) {
   var selected = event.detail.text;
});
```